# Autofac life time scope on serverless

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, serverless

Whats the best practice for life time scope when running on serverless (AWS lambda for example)
since its up for 15 min max is it a good practice to define all services as single instance?
thanks

```
builder.RegisterType<somService>().As<somService>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: You should use whatever lifetime is suitable for the class, irrespective of how the code is run.  Singleton is not generally a good fit for all classes, especially for message passing systems.  EF context will not work properly as a singleton/

Comment: It's impossible to answer this as asked. We'd need to know the lifetime of the class into which it is injected (not in minutes, but how is it scoped?) Then it depends on the class itself. The default (transient/instance per dependency) is usually safest if you're not sure and don't have a specific reason to avoid it. Creating a few extra class instances isn't usually a big deal.

Comment: What about a logger ? whould u define it as single instance ?